# How to create a class of classes

Tags: python-3.x, class

I'm trying to create two objects, `Shape` and `Entity`, where each have subclasses with the same names (`Line`, `Circle`, etc) but the ones in `Entity` will have extra properties such as `velocity` and `acceleration` and `Shape` is just graphical objects.

I need something like this:

```py
# shape.py

from .line import Line
from .circle import Circle

class Shape:
    ...

# entity.py

from .eline import Line
from .ecircle import Circle

class Entity:
    ...

# main.py

import Entity, Shape

circle = Shape.circle()
e_circle = Entity.circle()
```

To clarify, I saw something like this, but it doesn't quite work the way I want it to:

```py
# shape.py

from .line import Line
from .circle import Circle

class Shape:
    @property
    def Line(self):
        return Line

    @property
    def Circle(self):
        return Circle

# entity.py

from .eline import Line
from .ecircle import Circle

class Entity:
    @property
    def Line(self):
        return Line

    @property
    def Circle(self):
        return Circle
```

But apparently this requires that you have to instantiate `Shape` and `Entity` before you can use something like `line = Shape.Line()`

Comment: May I ask why you want these subclasses to have the same names? This might be bug-prone and reduce maintainability.

Comment: Mostly because they are pretty much identical, and the ones in `Entity` might just inherit from those within `Shape`

Comment: You can't have objects with the same name in a given namespace/scope without overwriting one, so if I am correctly inferring what you want to do you'll end up importing them with different names with `import x as y` or something like `eline.Circle` anyway. I'm not sure if I get what you want to do exactly, but I would still suggest to use something like `LineShape`, `CircleShape` for the shape classnames, and just `Line` and `Circle` for the entities or vice-versa, depending on which you will be using most / what is the least confusing. This could save you quite some headache down the line.

Comment: They wouldn't be imported on their own in the same scope, that's what I'm trying to bundle them up for. You would have to import `Shape` and/or `Entity` to access them by doing `Shape.line` or `Entity.line`, you wouldn't be able to import them alone

Comment: See the edit, I've tried to make it a bit more clear

Comment: I suppose your edit would work without instantiation if you use `@classmethod` instead of `@property`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you have the classes backwards. You're talking about instances of `Shape` and `Entity` which have accessors for different types.

It's hard to know without any context, but it looks to me like it would make more sense for your different types to be instances of a `Shape` class, and for them to be able to create the `Entity` version of themselves.

Something like this:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Entity:
    velocity: int


class Shape:
    def __init__(self, sides: int):
        self.sides = sides

    @abstractmethod
    @property
    def entity() -> Entity
        """ Returns the entity of this shape """

class Line(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(sides=1)
   
    @property
    def entity() -> Entity:
        return Entity(velocity=4)

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(sides=4)
   
    @property
    def entity() -> Entity:
        return Entity(velocity=2)
```

Then you can instantiate and access things like this:

```py
line1 = Line()
line2 = Line()
square = Square()

assert isinstance(line1, Shape)
assert isinstance(square, Shape)
assert isinstance(square.entity, Entity)
```